# How do I show part of next element in React Swipe

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, swipe

I'm using [React-Swipe](https://github.com/voronianski/react-swipe) in my project and want to show a part of next `div` on the screen.

Original:

[image: Only one div is being shown]

Required:

[image: I want to show part of next div so users know something is there.]

Comment: Isn't this how ReactSwipe is supposed to work out of the box?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't really get you. I meant that I want the users to know there is something after swiping also so I want to show a part of next div

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying, you want the next page to be partially visible even when it's not transitioning.

Comment: Yes @Aaron. Can you help me in this?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not sure what the solution would be. It looks like ReactSwipe does render all the pages to the DOM, so you might be able to just apply an offset with CSS to have them overlap.

Comment: I wonder why people are downvoting this question. Instead of downvoting, please ask what you don't understand or how does this question offend you?

Comment: how about http://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/stagepadding.html ?

Comment: Have you tried something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `React-swipe` render the content, to be more specific its creating the dom only when needed what you are asking for is not possible.

You will have to do some work around to do it.
I would suggest to look on this project which might be helpful for you:

react-swipeable-views
https://github.com/oliviertassinari/react-swipeable-views

You can use the `slide` & `slideStyle` to control how the slides will look like.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and for the link. It will be of help. :)